# Регулярное выражение (Замена: if => replace_if)

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Имеется строка в которой нужно заменить все if на replace_if при этом расположение этого if может быть любым, и если оно является частью другого слова, то тогда заменять не нужно...

Некоторые примеры замены

```
if(){ ...
else if(){ ...
```

Некоторые примеры когда заменять не нужно

```
var myif = function(){ ...
if24 = 24;
```

вот не знаю какое регулярное выражение нужно написать, чтобы работало правильно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте просто по границе слова находить:

```
var str = 'if(){ ... else if(){ ... var myif = function(){ ... if24 = 24;';
console.log(str.replace(/\b(if)\b/g, 'replace_if'));
```

Результат:

```
replace_if(){ ... else replace_if(){ ... var myif = function(){ ... if24 = 24;
```

Comment: дааа, то что нужно, спасибо огромное... решение оказывается легче чем можно было представить :)